# How to deploy strapi without credit card？

Tags: deployment, strapi, credit-card

it is such a pain, tried many platform: heroku, render, raiway (no free plan, credit card asked), digital ocean (accept paypal, i can try this), hostinger(paypal too).
anyway to bypass credit card? or

so digital ocean or hostinger, cost-wise?
I also need one custom domain.

tried tester credit card on some websites, no luck.

anyone could help?

help on bypassing credit card info or filling it